# How to close open connections in mysql with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

I just want to know how can i close all open connections from mysql and will it increase speed of my web site.

please take a look of mysql status output

```
Variable_name     Value
Aborted_connects    1
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal    0
Connection_errors_max_connections    0
Connection_errors_peer_address    0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap    0
Connections    252
Max_used_connections    6
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost    0
Ssl_client_connects    0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_finished_connects    0
Threads_connected    1
```

I am using code-igniter v3 for my project with the following db settings in database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '#######',
    'database' => '#######',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Your output status shows only one `Threads_connected`. If you are worried about  the `Connections` stat don't be. That is the number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server. In other words of the 252 connection attempts only one is currently connected. If this was a cell phone call log it would mean you got 252 calls and one is still in progress.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything.

I believe Codeigniter/MySQL will take care of closing connections for you as you do not have persistent connections enabled ('pconnect' => FALSE) this will allow connections to be closed automatically.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#manually-closing-the-connection

> While CodeIgniter intelligently takes care of closing your database connections, you can explicitly close the connection.
>
> $this->db->close();

Comment: connections are increasing